# Clear Vim Terminal window

Tags: terminal

Vim's new `:terminal` feature is pretty neat, but when I run something like a rails server, I want to be able to clear logging output every now and then.

The usual methods in a non-vim term window don't seem to work, like `<D-k>` (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> clears scrollback in Terminal.app on macOS), etc.

I've tried `<C-w>:Clear<CR>`, but it seems to be for something different as well.

If I weren't running a rails server, I could just type `clear` in the terminal.

I glanced through `:help :term`, and I'm not seeing what I want jump out at me.

Comment: Isnt `<C-l>` the standard clear key?

Comment: `C-l` is redraw. `C-l` actually does look like it clears the term window in Vim, but inconveniently it does not work when you have a process like rails server running. It has to be implemented by vim itself, because obviously if I use the terminal's actual clear key, it will wipe the whole screen including vim (which of course comes back if I hit `C-l` to redraw).

Perhaps this is just an edge case the new feature just hasn't addressed yet. Because it should be simple. You also can't `<C-\><C-n>` and delete the text, because modifiable is off and cannot be turned on for a running process.

Comment: Bizarre... if i do `:term` and then press `<C-l>` in my spawned shell it clears the term screen

Comment: Yes, but try that after starting a process that needs `C-c` to end. Or just do `sleep 10000` and try to `C-l` before it is done. This is actually the case for a non-vim terminal as well.

Comment: Well sure, the term never gets the clear. Hmm. I see the issue now

Comment: It will actually clear after the process ends. It has to wait though, which `super-k` on mac terminal would not. Just looking for the equivalent in vim term.

Comment: One workaround might be `set scbk=1` to make it forget the old lines, then `set scbk=100000` to get back to normal operation. It doesn't actually clear the window though.

Comment: @Amadan I think that one is for neovim (`'scrollback'`). → https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21260/how-to-clear-neovim-terminal-buffer For vim it's *'termwinscroll'* / *'twsl'*
 but it doesn't quite work. (still leave a screenful of lines) Neither does [`tput reset`, `printf '\ec'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5367068/5267751), (← by the way this makes the cursor blinks for some weird reason, [`printf '\e[2 q'` to reset](https://vt100.net/emu/ctrlseq_dec.html)) –

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/kassio/neoterm.

It provides A better terminal support.

You can use the command `:<terminal number>Tclear` to clear the terminal.
`:Tclear` for the last opened/active terminal (not sure which).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to clear the previous texts but if you have problem with scrolling back to the last command after executing it you can go to text mood by pressing `ctrl + W` `N` and set mark by pressing `m` `<any key on the keyboard>` press `i` to comeback to interactive mode and and execute your command and when you finished again go back to text mode by pressing `ctrl + W` `N` and go to the previously marked place by pressing `'` `<that key you have pressed before>`.

Answer (score 0):

Going through Vim's terminal.txt, I don't think you have a chance to clear the window.

It's because Vim doesn't do anything about `<c-l>`, just passing it as well as other typed keys to the running job, like bash or rails server. (when your focus is in the window)

The `<c-w>:clear` doesn't do the trick, either. The command is abbreviation of `:clearjumps` for newer Vim versions.

For normal terminal, like gnome-terminal or mac's terminal, it's the terminal dealing with your `<c-l> or <cmd-l>, <cmd-k>`. Vim's terminal looks not doing it.

However, I happened to try out a workaround. You can try it for your environment:

`:tmap <c-l> <c-w>s<c-w>c`

- tmap is mapping specific for terminal job mode.
- `<c-w>s` creates a new window, and when `<c-w>c` closes it and gets back, the terminal is cleared.

Comment: Sorry, but `c-w s c-w c` also does not work. You can try with sleep 10000. Text for processes in progress is not lost. There's probably situations where that is desirable. I agree, there are commands that vim is interpreting, and commands that the terminal app is interpreting. :clear and :Clear are different. vim terminal has some idea about breakpoints. I'm not entirely sure what it is about.

Comment: Let's check the version: I tested it with Vim 2.8.0 on ubuntu 18.04. However, I don't have gui on this server. I 'ssh' to the server and launch 'screen' to work with. Both sides are gnome-terminal.

I don't understand why you test with "sleep 10000". It doesn't have anything on screen for your to CLEAR. (If you run it by ":term sleep 10000".)

I test with ":term tail -f /var/log/syslog", which spit out log info from time to time. It works very well.

Comment: sleep is just an example of a long running process for someone who isn't using rails server or similar. Start :term without an argument. type echo 'test'. type sleep 10000. tail gives output instantly, so it's not a good example. You don't have to remap `<C-l>` for tail, it would work already because it is finished quickly.

Comment: There is some misunderstanding. Tail with option '-f' (follow) will track a growing file and keep printing to the screen. It's a good way to simulate the so-called 'log' behavior of a server. You can either test with it directly via `:term tail -f GROWING_FILE` or run it in the bash called `:term`.

Comment: In addition, `tail -f` will never come back until you press <ctrl-c>. It's better than `sleep 10000` because it has output from time to time.

Comment: I see, no I didn't realise that's what that option did. Your strategy still doesn't work.  My version output is this: vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Oct  3 2018 05:41:40)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-450
Compiled by Homebrew

Answer (score 0):

put this in ~/.zshrc:

```
# I export nvimServer_4_TermAPI, a env-var defined by myself, in some other place...
cle(){
    clear
    nvim --server "$nvimServer_4_TermAPI" \
         --remote-expr   "Tapi_clear(0)"
}
```

put this in init.vim:

```
    func! Tapi_clear(buf) abort
        try
            let ori_scrollback = getbufvar('', '&scrollback')
            setl scrollback=1
            sleep 100m
            exe 'setl scrollback=' . ori_scrollback
        catch
            echom 'Tapi_clear有错'
        endtry
        return ''
    endf
```

Inspired by this in autoload/neoterm.vim  of  https://github.com/kassio/neoterm:

```
        if get(a:opts, 'force_clear', 0)
            let l:bufname = bufname(l:instance.buffer_id)
            let l:scrollback = getbufvar(l:bufname, '&scrollback')

            call setbufvar(l:bufname, '&scrollback', 1)
            sleep 100m
            call setbufvar(l:bufname, '&scrollback', l:scrollback)
        end
```

About shell command `clear`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410708/the-easiest-way-to-clear-scrollback-buffer-of-terminal-some-deeper-explanation/741099#741099