# Unable to resume backgrounded Neovim-terminal-emulator-process using `kill -CONT`

Tags: vimscript, neovim, terminal-buffer

So, I'm trying to find an *actual* solution to [another question on here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21260/how-to-clear-neovim-terminal-buffer) that doesn't really have one. However, I'm running into a problem with backgrounding/foregrounding behaviour.

I need to background any processes spawned from the shell inside the terminal. So far, I have the following assembled:

```
function! s:terminal_clear()
   let l:scrollback = &scrollback
   set scrollback=1

   " Background any child-process. (No idea why <C-z> doesn't work.)
   let l:children = systemlist('pgrep -P '.b:terminal_job_pid)
   for pid in l:children[1:]
      call jobstart(['kill', '-STOP', pid])
   endfor

   " Space at the start of the command, plus additional space-return, prevents this from being added
   " to shell history. Requires `setopt histignorespace`.
   call chansend(&channel, " printf '\\n%.0s' {1..200}\<CR> \<CR>")
   call feedkeys("i\<C-l>")

   sleep 1000m

   for pid in l:children
      call jobstart(['kill', '-CONT', pid])
   endfor

   exec "set scrollback=".l:scrollback
endfunction
```

Unfortunately, the `for`-loop at the end, calling `kill -CONT ...` on each backgrounded PID, isn't functioning.

I can resume the suspended processes manually, using `fg`; but that's a bit of a nonstarter (doing so in the terminal-emulator-in-question, almost no matter what I do, leaves an  `fg` entry in the shell-history — completely defeating all the work I've been doing here in the first place to prevent *precisely that.*)

Does anybody know why `kill -CONT` might not work on a process inside Vim's terminal emulator? What am I doing incorrectly, here?

Comment: Just FYI if you're using Bash and add environment variable `HISTIGNORE` with value "fg" that command shouldn't be saved in your history. (Multiple commands can be added by separating them with `:`, e.g. `export HISTIGNORE=fg:bg`)

Comment: This is fantastic news, and will totally work for me! Unfortunately, I'd really like to push this up as a plugin that will work in a wide variety of situations; hopefully someone can come up with a good solution that'll work on other's machines …

Answer (score 1):

Note that *job control* in a shell is different from just sending a SIGSTOP signal to the process. It's actually much more about setting terminal settings, such as the controlling process group. So you can't really just foreground a suspended job in the shell by sending the processes in that job a SIGCONT (or, for that matter, any other signal.)

See also:

- [What makes Ctrl-Z different from `kill -STOP`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68622/281844)
- [Job Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control) in bash documentation
- [What is the purpose of the controlling terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404555/281844)